# get the value of variable name stored in SQL Sproc

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is what I am trying to do

```
  
Declare @Var varchar(50)
Declare @Num1 varchar(50)
Declare @Num2 varchar(50)
Declare @Counter smallint

Set @Counter=1
Set @Num1='Hello'
Set @Num2='Hi'

while (@Counter<2)
 begin
   Set @Var=N'@Num'+convert(varchar,@Counter)
   //Now I want to get the value of '@Num1' that is stored in @Var when @Counter=1
   //Help Needed
 Set @Counter=@Counter+1
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a very elegant solution to your problem but at least it solves it :)

```
 Declare @Var varchar(50)
 Declare @Num1 varchar(50)
 Declare @Num2 varchar(50)
 Declare @Counter smallint
 Declare @text varchar(50)

 Set @Counter=1
 Set @Num1='Hello'
 Set @Num2='Hi'

 while (@Counter<3)
 begin
 SET @text =
     CASE @Counter 
          WHEN 1 THEN @Num1
          WHEN 2 THEN @Num2
     END
 Set @Counter=@Counter+1
 print @text
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't do that directly; anything wrong with something like:

```
SET @Var = SELECT CASE @Counter WHEN 1 THEN @Num1 ELSE @Num2 END
```

If you have a lot of values, consider using a `#table` (temp table) or `@table` (table variable) - i.e.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ([Key] int NOT NULL, [Value] varchar(50))
```

then just `INSERT`/`UPDATE` into `@DATA`

```
SELECT @Var = [Value] FROM @Data WHERE [Key] = @Counter
```

Answer (score -1):

The value of @Num1 will be always 'Hello'.
The reason for that is that you are storing just a string into @Var.

Comment: Presumably the real problem is a little more complex